# ReSharper File Layout for explicit implemented interfaces

Tags: resharper

I'm trying to configure the File Layout of ReSharper in such a way that formatting the code does respect the 'StyleCop SA1202' rule.

See https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1202.md for more information.

Basically, this rule says that the order of elements is required to match a given pattern.
First 'Public', followed by 'Internal' ...

When I have a class that implements an interface explicit, it's in fact 'public'.
See the following code:

```
void IDisposable.Dispose()
{
    // Implementation
}
```

When I configure ReSharper File Layout with the following configuration:

```
<Entry DisplayName="Methods">
    <Entry.Match>
        <Kind Is="Method" />
    </Entry.Match>
    <Entry.SortBy>
        <Access Order="Public Internal Protected" />
    </Entry.SortBy>
</Entry>
```

The explicit implemented interface is placed as the after any public methods.

Is there any way to configure ReSharper's File Layout so that rule SA1202 is respected when using explicit interface implementations?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I am using the StyleCop file layout and added a special rule for Dispose methods at the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Patterns
    xmlns="urn:schemas-jetbrains-com:member-reordering-patterns">
    <TypePattern DisplayName="Non-reorderable types">
        <TypePattern.Match>
            <Or>
                <And>
                    <Kind Is="Interface" />
                    <Or>
                        <HasAttribute Name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.InterfaceTypeAttribute" />
                        <HasAttribute Name="System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComImport" />
                    </Or>
                </And>
                <Kind Is="Struct" />
                <HasAttribute Name="JetBrains.Annotations.NoReorderAttribute" />
                <HasAttribute Name="JetBrains.Annotations.NoReorder" />
            </Or>
        </TypePattern.Match>
    </TypePattern>
    <TypePattern DisplayName="xUnit.net Test Classes" RemoveRegions="All">
        <TypePattern.Match>
            <And>
                <Kind Is="Class" />
                <HasMember>
                    <And>
                        <Kind Is="Method" />
                        <HasAttribute Name="Xunit.FactAttribute" Inherited="True" />
                    </And>
                </HasMember>
            </And>
        </TypePattern.Match>
        <Entry DisplayName="Setup/Teardown Methods">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Or>
                    <Kind Is="Constructor" />
                    <And>
                        <Kind Is="Method" />
                        <ImplementsInterface Name="System.IDisposable" />
                    </And>
                </Or>
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Kind Order="Constructor" />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="All other members" />
        <Entry DisplayName="Test Methods" Priority="100">
            <Entry.Match>
                <And>
                    <Kind Is="Method" />
                    <HasAttribute Name="Xunit.FactAttribute" />
                </And>
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Name />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
    </TypePattern>
    <TypePattern DisplayName="NUnit Test Fixtures" RemoveRegions="All">
        <TypePattern.Match>
            <And>
                <Kind Is="Class" />
                <HasAttribute Name="NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute" Inherited="True" />
            </And>
        </TypePattern.Match>
        <Entry DisplayName="Setup/Teardown Methods">
            <Entry.Match>
                <And>
                    <Kind Is="Method" />
                    <Or>
                        <HasAttribute Name="NUnit.Framework.SetUpAttribute" Inherited="True" />
                        <HasAttribute Name="NUnit.Framework.TearDownAttribute" Inherited="True" />
                        <HasAttribute Name="NUnit.Framework.FixtureSetUpAttribute" Inherited="True" />
                        <HasAttribute Name="NUnit.Framework.FixtureTearDownAttribute" Inherited="True" />
                    </Or>
                </And>
            </Entry.Match>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="All other members" />
        <Entry DisplayName="Test Methods" Priority="100">
            <Entry.Match>
                <And>
                    <Kind Is="Method" />
                    <HasAttribute Name="NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute" />
                </And>
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Name />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
    </TypePattern>
    <TypePattern DisplayName="StyleCop Classes, Interfaces, &amp; Structs" RemoveRegions="All">
        <TypePattern.Match>
            <Or>
                <Kind Is="Class" />
                <Kind Is="Struct" />
                <Kind Is="Interface" />
            </Or>
        </TypePattern.Match>
        <Entry DisplayName="Constants">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Constant" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Fields">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Field" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Constructors">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Constructor" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Destructors">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Destructor" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Delegates">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Delegate" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Events">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Event" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Enums">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Enum" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Interfaces">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Interface" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Properties">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Property" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Indexers">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Indexer" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Methods">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Method" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Structs">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Struct" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Classes">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Kind Is="Class" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
        <Entry DisplayName="Dispose">
            <Entry.Match>
                <Name Is="Dispose" />
            </Entry.Match>
            <Entry.SortBy>
                <Access Order="Public Internal ProtectedInternal Protected Private" />
                <Static />
                <Readonly />
            </Entry.SortBy>
        </Entry>
    </TypePattern>
</Patterns>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new region where you capture properties that are private and that implement an interface and in the name of the interface use the regex "I.*"

```
<Region Name="Explicit interface implementation">
  <Entry DisplayName="Interface properties">
    <Entry.Match>
      <And>
        <Kind Is="Property" />
        <ImplementsInterface Name="I.*" />
        <Access Is="Private" />
      </And>
    </Entry.Match>
  </Entry>
</Region>
```